# Cosmology model with equation of state $P=\epsilon / (\epsilon+1)$

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, cosmology, pressure

In my cosmology course I came across the universe with the equation of state
$$
 P=\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon+1},
$$
where $P$ is the pressure and $\epsilon$ is the energy density. The task was to figure out which energy conditions this satisfies and do some calculations but it was provided without context. I am wondering if this thing has a name? Is it just a "homework" model or does it have any applications? What would be a properties of such an universe?

Comment: Is $P$ pressure and $\epsilon$ energy density? Or what are the symbols?

Comment: Exactly like that, yes

Answer (score 1):

Cosmological equation of state is $$p=\omega \rho \tag 1$$, where $\omega$ is
[dimensionless equation parameter](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.0589.pdf) having form :

$$\omega = \frac {1} {3 (Kx^\alpha + 1)} \tag 2$$

Parameter $x=1$, identifies boundary condition when universe undergoes transition from radiation phase to dust phase, hence equation (2) becomes :

$$\omega = \frac {1} {3 (K + 1)} \tag 3.$$

Except for the factor 3 equation (3) is very similar to your given one in a question, namely here $K=\epsilon^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

When the energy density $\epsilon\ll 1$, the pressure is
$$ P = \epsilon.$$
This describes "kination", a cosmological phase named by [Joyce (1997)](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9606223), who considered how this phase could facilitate baryogenesis. It was also considered earlier by [Spokoiny (1993)](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9306008), who suggested that primordial inflation could transition into kination, essentially because inflation is driven by a slow-rolling scalar field (potential energy dominates) and kination is driven by a fast-rolling scalar field (kinetic energy dominates).

When the energy density $\epsilon\gg 1$, the pressure is
$$P=1\ll\epsilon.$$
This is effectively matter domination. So you have a universe that transitions from matter domination into kination as the energy density drops below 1. This does not happen naturally, because the energy density of a kination fluid scales as $a^{-6}$, dropping faster than the matter density ($\propto a^{-3}$) as the universe expands. But you could probably accomplish it with a field theory model, for example an oscillating scalar field (which has $P\ll\epsilon$) that transitions into a fast-rolling phase ($P=\epsilon$) due to some feature in the field's potential.

I'm not familiar with an existing model that realizes this behavior. I suspect there isn't one, because the people thinking about super-Planckian energies ($\epsilon\gg 1$) are mostly inflation theorists, and this behavior doesn't include an inflationary phase.